# What are best practices for documenting MEAN stack web applications?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I am from Java programming background. I know how to do documentation there. We can document each method and each attribute of a class in java environment.

Since last year, I have been working on a web application using MEAN stack. At first, I just added single-line comments for my own understanding. I think there should some standard way of documenting web applications.

Roughly, I have following code:

- Angularjs Controllers
- Angularjs Routes
- Angularjs Services
- MongoDb Collections defined on server side (Node)
- ExpressJS Configuration Code
- ExpressJS Routes and their handlers
- REST API
- Socket.IO Code

In short, I want to do this:

- Documentation inside the code in form of comments (standard way)
- Make a separate documentation word file or HTML file

**Edit**

I don't mean that I want to do similar type of code documentation as it is done in Java. I want to understand how to do it in MEAN based applications in a standard way. Those who use MEAN boilerplates know there are separate folders for client side code and for server side code. Within them, there are separate folders for configuration, route handlers, authentication, views etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)?

Comment: yes, can it also make track of my directory structure. In mean boilerplates, directory structure matters i.e. that is client folder contains client code, and within it auth folder contain authentication service code etc. Here is the [example directory](https://github.com/sojharo/fullstack-demo).